# How can I look up a SoftLayer image template by it's global identifier?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to use the api look up a public image template using it’s global identifier in order to find out it’s ID, to pass into the reload call.
I thought I could do this using this:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups?objectFilter={%22blockDeviceTemplateGroups%22:{%22globalIdentifier%22:{%22operation%22:%222e61f677-752b-4020-a447-b138f5daa387%22}}}
```

However it seems that other SoftLayer accounts aren’t returned the public image using this API, and I need this to work for all SoftLayer accounts.

I could use this API:

```
`https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/getPublicImages?objectFilter={%22publicImages%22:{%22globalIdentifier%22:{%22operation%22:%222e61f677-752b-4020-a447-b138f5daa387%22}}}`
```

but I can’t get the filter to work - it just returns the full list still.

Am I doing the filter wrong?
Or is there another API I should use, where the filter would work? (And which works for all SL users in all SL accounts)
Or do I have to retrieve the full list and filter myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

“The publicImages parameter in your request is not required, please use the following request to retrieve the public image template according to its globalIdentifier (following values should be changed by your credentials and globalIdentifier string respectively: $username, $apiKey – and $globalIdentifier).

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/getPublicImages?objectFilter={"globalIdentifier":{"operation":"$globalIdentifier"}}
```

The getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups method used in the first request will only retrieve the template group objects (image templates) which belong to your account only. While getPublicImages method will retrieve all the public image templates (this one is for Softlayer's accounts).

For more references about this and objectFilters please see below:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/getPublicImages 
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters